# Prove that the closure of the set of functions with bounded derivatives is the set of functions satisfy the Lipschitz condition

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm reading the book "*Elements of the theory of functions and functional analysis*". Here I quote the following:

> (1) Let $M_K$ be the set of all functions $f$ in $C[a, b]$ which satisfy a so-called Lipschitz condition
> $$
>        \vert f(t_1) - f(t_2) \vert \le K \vert t_1 - t_2 \vert
> $$
> where $K$ is a constant. The set $M_k$ is closed. It coincides with the closure of the set of all differentiable functions which are such that $\vert f'(t) \vert \le K$.

For convenience, set
$$
    D_K = \{f\text{ differentiable on } [a,b]: \vert f'(t) \vert \le K \ \forall t \in (a,b)\}
$$
and on $C[a,b]$, we use the sup norm.

I'm able to check the fact that $M_k$ is a closed set, and $[D_K] \subseteq M_K$ ($[D_K]$ denotes the closure of $D_K$). However, I don't know how to show $M_K \subseteq [D_K]$, that is, for any Lipschitz-continuous function $f$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there is a differentiable function $g_\epsilon$ on $[a, b]$ such that
$$
    \sup_{x \in [a, b]} \vert f(x) - g_\epsilon(x)\vert < \epsilon
$$
and $\vert g_\epsilon'(t) \vert \le K \ \forall t \in (a, b)$. Any hints are appreciated, thank you !

**Edit:** The condition $\sup \vert f - g_\epsilon \vert < \epsilon$ can be satisfied by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, but I have no idea how to control $g_\epsilon'$

Comment: Did you try convolution with a *mollifier*?

Comment: Another thing you could try is noting that a Lipschitz continuous function with Lipschitz constant $K$ is differentiable a.e. with its derivative measurable and bounded by $K$. So you can then approximate the derivative by a continuous function bounded by $K$ and take its integral to obtain $g_\epsilon$.